Getting error SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed
I am connecting MS SQL server 2008 database using jdk 1.8.371 and spring boot 2.1.5. i am getting error "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed". i am not getting data from database below is a code
Databse detailsjdbcUrl: jdbc:sqlserver://IPAddress:1433;databaseName=MyDatabase;integratedSecurity=false;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;sslProtocol=TLSv1
driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Class.forName(dbDriver);
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword)) {
    try (PreparedStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall(dbQuery)) {
        try (ResultSet dbSet = cStmt.executeQuery()) {
            while (dbSet.next()) {
                    TransId = dbSet.getString("TRANS_ID");
                }
            }
        }
    }

My query :
Select TRANS_ID From Transactionlog;

I disabled jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=None in java.security file after that i am able to connect database but not able to fetch data. i also set system.setProperties but not able to get data

FYI, SQL Server 2008 ran completely out of support almost 5 years ago; getting your instance upgraded to a support version is long overdue and you really need to prioritise getting onto a fully supported and secure version ASAP.

What's the error you're getting after fixing the java.security file? What happens when you debug your code?

I suspect you should check your JDBC driver version and then look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver16#sql-version-compatibility

MS SQL server 2008 supports only TLSv1.0. while jdk 1.8.371 by default support TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3. To resolve this issue i have changed below 2 properties in java.security file on path jdk-1.8\jre\lib\security
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=None

jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=None

By making above changes i am able to connect and fetch data from MS SQL server 2008
